# Echo a function inside a function

Tags: php, functions

I have to create a shortcode so I can paste the shortcode inside the mobile menu plugin's options, the plugin doesn't accept PHP so I can't do `<span class="header-cart-total"><?php echo edd_cart_total(); ?></span>`

The issue I'm having is echo'ing `edd_get_cart_total()` which causes a white screen on my website. I have to echo it or the cart total amount price doesn't show up fully-formatted. How do I echo it? This is in my functions.php file:

```
function eddminicartfunc() {
        return 
        '<div class="mobilemenucart">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                <span class="header-cart-total"> ' . echo edd_get_cart_total() . ' </span>
                <span class="header-cart edd-cart-quantity">
                ' .  edd_get_cart_quantity() .'
                </span>
        </div>';
}
add_shortcode('eddminicart', 'eddminicartfunc');
```

Comment: Why do you need to `echo` it?  If `edd_get_cart_total()` returns a string, you can just concatenate it. Like: `<span class="header-cart-total"> ' . edd_get_cart_total() . ' </span>`

Comment: When I don't echo it, the amount comes back un-formatted. So when I echo it in my header.php file using `<?php echo edd_cart_total(); ?>` it returns $0.00, when I just use ' . edd_get_cart_total() . ' in my functions.php file it returns 0, no dollar sign or decimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` is a PHP language construct which pushes values to the output buffer. It does not have a return value, so concatenating it with a string would cause everything after the `echo` to immediately be sent to the output buffer, and everything prior to `echo` to compose the concatenated string. This is such a misuse of `echo` that PHP itself doesn't actually allow it - if you had WordPress debugging enabled you would see an error similar to

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

This error is what is causing your white screen - when not in debug mode, WordPress suppresses error output to avoid exposing potentially sensitive information to end-users.

You shouldn't use `echo` in shortcode logic, as internally WordPress does more processing with a shortcode's return value. So using `echo` in a shortcode has a good chance to mess up your final markup.

The inclusion of the `echo` before the `edd_get_cart_total()` does not result in currency formatting. I've dug through [the plugin in question's source code](https://github.com/easydigitaldownloads/easy-digital-downloads/blob/master/includes/cart/class-edd-cart.php#L1150) just to be sure. Rather, it's more likely that some function is hooked to the `edd_get_cart_total` filter to format the output in templates (thus formatting the total when you used it in your `header.php` template), however within the context of a shortcode that filter is not attached.

Conveniently, the plugin provides the `ebb_cart_total()` function which will always produce a currency-formatted total string. The first argument to the function is `$echo` which is true by default, and will cause the function to display the total instead of returning it - which, as detailed earlier, is not something you want to do in a shortcode - so set this argument to `false` to have the function return a string which you may concatenate with the rest of your shortcode markup.

All together:

```
function eddminicartfunc() {
  return 
    '<div class="mobilemenucart">
       <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
       <span class="header-cart-total"> ' . edd_cart_total( false ) . ' </span>
       <span class="header-cart edd-cart-quantity">' . edd_get_cart_quantity() . '</span>
    </div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'eddminicart', 'eddminicartfunc' );
```

Comment: No wonder I couldn't figure this out, a bit above my head. That worked! I definitely learned something today. Thanks for the lesson @bosco

Comment: No problem ;) . The `echo` seemingly changing the behavior of the proceeding function threw me for a loop - I couldn't help but investigate

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as to where you are trying to insert your code and what limits it has but try it like this and see if it works?

```
function eddminicartfunc() {

    $foo = '<div class="mobilemenucart">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                        <span class="header-cart-total"> ' . echo edd_get_cart_total() . ' </span>
                        <span class="header-cart edd-cart-quantity">
                        ' .  edd_get_cart_quantity() .'
                        </span>
                </div>';
                return $foo;
        }
add_shortcode('eddminicart', 'eddminicartfunc');
```

Comment: That also gives me a blank, white screen.

Comment: What mobile menu are you using?

Comment: Its called Responsive Menu Pro, that's not really relevant though I don't think. The plugin loads other shortcodes fine. All I'm doing is creating a shortcode in my functions.php file so I can paste that shortcode into the plugin options. I'm just asking how to echo a function in my current code or if it's not possible and I should re-write the code.